# radius of convergence of Taylor expansion of $e^x$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

The Taylor expansion of $e^x$ at $x=0$ is $1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3! + ...$

but I get that this expansion is true for all $x$ (not necessarily around $x=0$).

can someone prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Apply the ratio test.

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$$

**More Details**

Applying the Taylor sequence $a_n = x^n/n!$ as requested above, we obtain

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$

Which means the limit of

$$\frac{x}{n+1}$$

Which goes to zero as $n\to +\infty$, hence, being less than $1$ it does converge and the radius of convergence is infinite.

This means the Taylor series holds $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

**Radius of Convergence**

$$R = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$$

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: @jack.math Edited!